# How accounts are protected from sending money from it to smart contract

Tags: solidity, accounts

I wondering how accounts are protected from sending money from it to smart contract

example code:

smart contract

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.9.0;

contract TransferService {
    mapping(address => uint) public balances;

    function deposit() public payable {
        balances[msg.sender] += msg.value;
    }
}
```

client

```
const web3 = new Web3("http://localhost:7545")
const [firstAccountAddress, secondAccountAddress] = await web3.eth.getAccounts();

const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, "0x3C9d9a1dEE2AAC5C7e53cB29cc1A28322caDa377");
await contract.methods.deposit().send({from: firstAccountAddress, value: web3.utils.toWei('3', 'ether')});
await contract.methods.deposit().send({from: secondAccountAddress, value: web3.utils.toWei('3', 'ether')});
```

how `firstAccountAddress` and `secondAccountAddress` are protected from not taking money from them if somebody knows they address?

If I run this code on my local network(ganche) I can take all money from these accounts, how account can protect themselves from that? I read that ganche have accounts private keys on their node and because of that this is possible here, but when I move to testnet/mainnet I need to put more info not just account address to performe such call as

```
await contract.methods.deposit().send({from: firstAccountAddress, value: web3.utils.toWei('3', 'ether')});
```

?

Comment: Hi Damian, welcome to the Ethereum StackExchange. Nobody can take money from an externally owned account (EOA) if the person controlling it did not cryptographically sign a transaction. Suggested reading: [Ethereum wallets](https://ethereum.org/en/wallets/).

Comment: Please leave a real answer and not just a comment @PaulRazvanBerg :)

Comment: @LauriPeltonen I was too lazy to write a full answer 

Answer (score 0):

When transactions are sent to nodes to be included on the Ethereum blockchain, the node will check to see if the transaction has been properly signed, otherwise it will be rejected. Transactions have to be signed using the private key of an address. Addresses and public keys are incapable of creating authentic signatures for transactions--the private key must be used.

On a testnet or mainnet, you will need to add line of code such as the following in order to sign the transaction before sending:

```
const signPromise = web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(tx, privateKey);
```

Ganache local network uses "unlocked" accounts which is why you are seeing a different behavior there.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks for answer!, I'm wondering where should I add privateKey when calling smart contract method to sign transaction made by method call, when I look to https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.7.3/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-send I'm able to send money during execution smart contract method but don't see option to pass privateKey like in https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.7.3/web3-eth.html#signtransaction. https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.7.3/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-send shoudn't be used on production cuz of lack privateKey option?

Comment: found answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50434248/call-contract-methods-with-web3-from-newly-created-account